# How to set the global text of title in Site.Master page using ASP.NET MVC 2 & 3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, master-pages, title

I am using ASP.NET MVC 2 & 3 with aspx View not Razor View, my question is:

How to set the title in Site.Master page? I wish every pages which use Site.Master page can add a Master title follow the page title show like: "Index -MasterTitle" ; "About -MasterTitle".

I've try in Site.Master page and it's doesn't work:

```
<title><asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="TitleContent" runat="server" />
    -MasterTitle
</title>
```

so I try to use asp:Literal server control:

```
<title><asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="TitleContent" runat="server" />
    <asp:Literal  runat="server">-MasterTiltle</asp:Literal>
</title>
```

Or:

```
<title><asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="TitleContent" runat="server" />
    <asp:Literal  runat="server" Text="-MasterTiltle"></asp:Literal>
</title>
```

fine, it's solve the problem, but later I want to load the value of MasterTitle from web.config, I've  try:

```
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="TitleContent" runat="server" />
    <asp:Literal runat="server">
        <%: System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SiteTile"] %>
    </asp:Literal>
</asp:Literal>
```

compiler toled me a server control can't contain a child control, so I try the other:

```
<title>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="TitleContent" runat="server" />
        <asp:Literal ID="ltlTitleBack" runat="server" Text='<%: System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SiteTile"] %>' > 
    </asp:Literal>
</title>
```

it's compiler ok but not the answer what I want cause it show: "**pagetilte <%: System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SiteTile"] %>**"

and later I found a way can solve this problem here: [CodeExpressionBuilder](http://weblogs.asp.net/infinitiesloop/archive/2006/08/09/The-CodeExpressionBuilder.aspx)

but I think that is not a proper solution cause I should set too many things that not relate to ASP MVC. Is there any better solution can solve this problem?

Note:

1. I don't want set the value of MasterTitle in every pages not Site.Master page, that's a stupid way.
2. I don't want set the value of MasterTitle in Controller or Action or Model, that's not right.
3. I don't want set the value of MasterTitle via ViewData.
4. I don't want to use [CodeExpressionBuilder](http://weblogs.asp.net/infinitiesloop/archive/2006/08/09/The-CodeExpressionBuilder.aspx).
5. I'm not use Razor View.

thanks for any help.

Edit: Actually I want something like web.config so I can change the value of MasterTitle when server is running. :)

Comment: could you please elaborate what was wrong with the very first approach you presented? It seems to me that it was the best one, and most easily tailored to your needs

Comment: @Zruty: ya I agree with you, I am insist on doing something between the "answer" and the "right answer". :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had similar issues and here is what I had to use:

```
<title>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="TitleContent" runat="server" /><%= "-MasterTitle" %>
</title>
```

Comment: Thanks man~ that's exactly what I want :), thanks for your help. that problem killing me whole month

Answer (score 1):

You should use your Resource files for this kind of text...

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227427.aspx

Not only does it let you set the text in a nice central place, but it is designed for this exact purpose - it will also make it easier for your to create regional language versions of your website later on!

Comment: thank you Sohnee, is there possible to change the value of Resource file when server is running? cause web.config can do this. :)

Comment: It is technically possible, although not quite in the same way. If you update your resources, they get compiled into the DLL (you might have resources for 100 different languages). So you can drop the new DLL into the bin folder and IIS will automatically recycle the app pool and pick up the changes.

Comment: Wow! thank you, I learn a lots about resources, I wish I can give you the other 10 point :), thanks again

Comment: Not a problem - glad to help!